# How I set the customer based discount on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer

I want to set customer based discount in Magento 2.

For example: Xyz 10 % discount ABC 5 % discount.

Comment: Do you need same coupon but different discount or you want assign particular coupon to specific customer?

Comment: want to assign particular coupon to specific customer

Comment: There is no any built in functionality like this for that you have to do customisation or need to install extension.